# Suddenly swifyJson cannot resolve alamofire data

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I use swiftyJson to resolve JSON. When I use

```
jsonArray = JSON(retValue)
```

In swift language after get data by alamofire, it's always work OK.

But now when I change something from storyboard, it don't work. I use `print(jasonArray)`
it's return "null". I'm sure retValue has data because I can use

```
String(data: retValue, encoding: .utf8)
```

To get the right data.

Then I debug jsonArray=JSON (retvalue) sentence, I use F7 to enter swiftyJson in Xcode, I can see the follow:

```
do {
    let object: Any = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: opt)
    self.init(jsonObject: object)
} catch let aError as NSError {
    if error != nil {
        error?.pointee = aError
    }
    self.init(jsonObject: NSNull())
}
```

The result is it only excuse the first sentence

```
let object: Any = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: opt)
```

then it enter catch and return null.

why swiftyJson don't Work?

Comment: What is `retValue`?

Answer (score 0):

I have solve my problem. In all, swift has a pool ability for resolve json at least at swift 3 platform.